# Meaning of "It will be but ..."

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

The structure used is strange for me :

It will be but a pitiful plastiche

What does " It will be but " means?
And the phrase pitiful plastiche is negative, isnt it?

Comment: "It will be **but** X" has the sense of "All it will be is X".

Comment: By the way, the title of your question doesn't tell us what you want to ask.

Comment: I think it's pastiche, not plastiche, which seems to be a word having something to do with plastic.

Answer (score 2):

This usage of "but" is essentially short for "nothing but". A famous example is in the song "Row, Row, Row Your Boat", where we have the line:

> "Life is but a dream".

This means, "Life is nothing but a dream", or "Life is a dream, and nothing more than that."

The same thing applies here. "It will be nothing but a pitiful plastiche." "It will be a pitiful plastiche, and nothing more than that."

As noted in the comments above, the word "plastiche" is not an English word, and appears to be a typo; perhaps "pastiche" is intended? In either event, "pitiful" is certainly a negative word, and one does not get the sense that anything positive is being said here.